# How to make a number go up one with a button (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, numbers, var

**I am super confused about javascript and how I make this number go up, if you could tell me how it would be great. (I am a bit new to javascript so sorry if this makes no sense and let me know in the comments if I should provide more but that code down there is the entire thing)**

### Code

````
  <head>
    <div class="center">
      <h1 id="title">
        This number will increase.
      </h1>
      <p id="button">
        0
      </p>
      <a
        class="button"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: calibri;"
        id="numbergoup"
        onclick="myFunction()"
        >Number go up</a
      >
    </div>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
   
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      #button {
        border-style: solid;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      div.center {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #numbergoup {
        background-color: tomato;
        padding: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function myFunction(){
  const numberElement = document.getElementById("button");
  const number = parseInt(numberElement.innerText, 10) + 1;
  numberElement.innerText = number;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">0</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Number go up</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Your Neat Code you neet to increment that number as I do let me know if you need any other help

> ```
> <style>
> html{
> font-family: calibri;
> }
>   #button {
>     border-style: solid;
>     padding: 20px;
>     color: black; 
>   }
>   div.center {
>     text-align: center;
>   }
>   #increment {
>     background-color: tomato;
>     padding: 20px;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 25%;
>     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
>     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
>   }
>   #reset {
>     background-color: yellow;
>     padding: 20px;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 35%;
>     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
>     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
>   }
> </style>
>
> <div class="center">
>   <h1 id="title">
>     This number will increase.
>   </h1>
>   <p id="button">
>     0
>   </p>
>   <button
>     class="button"
>     id="increment"
>     onclick="numberGoUp()"
>     >Number go up</button
>   >
>
>   <button
>     class="button"
>     id="reset"
>     onclick="reset()"
>     >Reset</button
>   >
> </div>
>
> <script>
>   function numberGoUp() {
>       const counter = document.querySelector('#button');
>     let countValue = Number(counter.innerHTML);
>     countValue++;
>     counter.innerHTML = countValue;
>   }
>   function reset(){
>       const counter = document.querySelector('#button');
>     counter.innerHTML = 0;
>   }
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <style>
        #button {
            border-style: solid;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        div.center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #numbergoup {
            background-color: tomato;
            padding: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
    <h1 id="title">
        This number will increase.
    </h1>
    <p id="number">0</p>
    <button
        class="button"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: calibri;"
        id="numbergoup"
        onclick="myFunction()"
        >Number go up</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var numberValue = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
        numberValue++;

        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = numberValue;
    }
</script>
```